# How to cast const std::string& to integer?

Tags: c++

I have a variable like this:

```
const std::string& iterations = "30";
```

I want to use it to determine number of iterations for a "for" loop:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ) {
  // do something
}
```

How to do that? I know I can cast to string like this:

```
iterations.c_str();
```

So I tried c_int() but it won't work:

```
iterations.c_int();
```

Comment: Why use it in the first place? What's the use? And remember: You're trying to cast a reference, not just any string!

Comment: It's a `const`, why is it set as a `string`? Why not make it `const int` or some integral type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this:

```
int foo = atoi( iterators.c_str() );
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) for a description of `atoi`.

Answer (score 8):

In order of preference:

`boost::lexical_cast`

`atoi`

`std::stringstream`

`sscanf`

Note that `lexical_cast` is simple enough to be written here:

```
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>

struct bad_lexical_cast : std::exception {};

template<typename Target, typename Source>
Target lexical_cast(Source arg)
{
  std::stringstream interpreter;
  Target result;
  if(!(interpreter << arg) ||
     !(interpreter >> result) ||
     !(interpreter >> std::ws).eof())
    throw bad_lexical_cast();
  return result;
}
```

it converts anything into anything. (Credits: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm )

Usage : `int iter = lexical_cast<int>(iterations)`

Comment: `stringstream` before `atoi`… it can be done in one line and it allows error checking. `for ( int i = 0, iterations_i, success = (bool) stringstream( iterations ) >> iterations_i; success && i < iterations_i; ++ i ) { ... }`… or many other stylistic variants, which `lexical_cast` is little more than anyway.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I prefer `lexical_cast` because I never have to look anything in a manual. I prefer `atoi` to naked `stringstream` because `stringstream` is verbose to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
int iters = atoi(str.c_str());
```

You can also use a more modern, C++ style method by utilizing a stringstream

```
string s = "1234";
stringstream ss(s); 

int i;
ss >> i;
```

Answer (score 1):

zou just need to use simple function -  atoi(iterations.c_str());

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
istringstream ss(iterators);

int count;
ss >> count;

for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string to a number using the following function:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ios>

template<class T>
bool str2num( const std::string& s, T *pNumber, 
              std::ios_base::fmtflags fmtfl = std::ios_base::dec )
{
  std::istringstream  stm( s.c_str() );

  stm.flags( fmtfl );
  stm >> (*pNumber);
  return stm.fail() == false;
}
```

For converting to an integer call as follows:

```
int output;

bool success = str2num( iterations, &output );
```